# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null error

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I know there were a lot of answers related to this error, but I still don't know how to solve it... I'm trying to make the database connection, which would connect to the database and insert user's entered values in it and i got this error. I've created 2 files (with different classes):

Here is a connection file:

```
<?php
class Connection {
    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
 public function __construct() {
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees';
// Setting options
$options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// Making the connection to the database
try {
$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
$this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$connection = new connection();
?>
```

And here is users.php file:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
class Users {
public $name;
public $surname;
public $employmentDate;
public function __construct()
{
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$this->name = $_POST['name'];
$this->surname = $_POST['surname'];
$this->employmentDate = $_POST['employmentDate'];
}
}
// Inserting users values to the database table
public function insertUserValues() {
 $stmt= 'INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date) VALUES (:name,:surname,:employmentDate)';
 $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare();
 $stmt->bindValue(':name',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':surname',$surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':employmenDate',$employmentDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute([$this->name,$this->surname,$this->employmentDate]);
}
}
$users = new Users();
$users->insertUserValues();
?>
```

I guess there are some mistakes in code structure, but I'm just learning, so. The code line which throws the error 18 line in users.php file:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare();
```

Please someone tell me where I am doing a mistake, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have somes mistakes in your code. Try to use this lines :

Connection file :

```
<?php
class Connection {
    public $dbh;

    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees';
        // Setting options
        $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Making the connection to the database
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

$connection = new connection();
```

users.php file :

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';
class Users {
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $employmentDate;
    public $connection;

    public function __construct($connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            $this->name = $_POST['name'];
            $this->surname = $_POST['surname'];
            $this->employmentDate = $_POST['employmentDate'];
        }
    }

    // Inserting users values to the database table
    public function insertUserValues() {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date) VALUES (:name,:surname,:employmentDate)';
        $stmt = $this->connection->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name',$this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':surname',$this->surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':employmentDate',$this->employmentDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}   

$users = new Users($connection);
$users->insertUserValues();
```

Explanations :

- You have to pass the $connection variable to your users class (or import it with `global $connection;`)
- Your connection file has to make visible the dbh property, otherwise you will not be able to make any query on your database
- PDO [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method is waiting for a query in first argument
- You don't need to pass an array to execute() method if you already have binded your values before

Comment: I still got the same error. It also says that $dbh property in the same line is undefined

Comment: Just updated my answer. Hope this will help !

Comment: Thank you, at least it's passing to the next line errors :)

Comment: could you help me to solve one more error? It's in the execute statement and it says "execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given". My code line is:

     `$stmt->execute($query);`

Comment: Keep your stmt->bindValue() calls and remove the parameter to execute() ;-) execute don't need any params if you already bind all the values

Comment: But if I am removing execute() parameter it says 'parameter was not defined' in that line...

Comment: You have a typo in the last bindValue. replace :employmenDate with :employmentDate ;-)

Comment: Meh, I've edited the line, but it's still printing 'Column 'name' cannot be null'. Thank you for the help anyway m8, good luck. :)

Comment: Got it. Just updated my answer, you had to replace $name by $this->name and so on !

Comment: To help you to find this problems, you can add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the start of your PHP files

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `$this` from outside the class scope. You probably want

```
$connection->dbh->prepare();
```

Comment: I've just changed  my line with yours, but it didn't helped and I got one new eror, which says that connection is undefined

Comment: It is, because you use it in the function and it is a global. Add `global $connection` to the top of your function. You issue here is not about PDO, but about scope and variables. Make sure you understand PHP basics before you continue with database stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your connection class to a singleton:

```
class Connection {

    private static $instance = null;

    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
    public function __construct() {
       $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees';
      // Setting options
      $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     // Making the connection to the database
     try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
       $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
             self::$instance = new self();
        }
        call_user_func_array([ self::$instance->dbh, $name], $args);
    }   

}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
 Connection::prepare(); //or connection::any_pdo_function
```