# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null [C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\core\classes\user.php on line 19]

Tags: php, pdo

On logging in, This error pops up.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\core\classes\user.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\includes\login.php(17): User->login('user@email.com', 'passwordofuser') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\index.php(59): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\core\classes\user.php on line 19**

I'm a beginner in PHP and was trying to validate the "entered" email and password by connecting it to SQL DATABASE. I wanted to display an "error" message if the email or password is not available in database.
This is user.php.

The error is at line 19.

```
 $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password");
```

user.php

```
    <?php
class User
{
    protected $pdo;
    
    function _construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function checkInput($var)
    {
        $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = stripcslashes($var);
        return $var;
    }
    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password",md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
            header('Location: home.php');
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now, here is my connection.php

```
<?php
    $dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=tweety';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Connnection error! ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

**Here is login.php**[image]

I know that this question is asked previously but i can't help myself find a solution.Any help would be appreciated.
**WHAT I TRIED:**

1. Tried checking for typo error in connection.php
2. Tried restarting my SQL server from XAMPP.
3. Tried referring other ["stackoverflow" questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643681/uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null-error)

Comment: add this line 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
in your connection.php after $pdo and then see

Comment: @ArifulIslam [I did what you said](https://ibb.co/J3PC0Kk) but still exactly the same error pops up but i really appreciate your suggestion brother.

Comment: now add this line also 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

Comment: where you have called your User class for accessing method?

Comment: @ArifulIslam [Still the same error :(](https://ibb.co/5RryB0R)

Comment: I think your connetion is not passing

Comment: @ArifulIslam You can check login.php(last image on my question) for that.

Comment: from where you are getting $getFromU?

Comment: @ArifulIslam Look,At line 17 in user.php a "login" function is created.takes the value of "$email" and "$password" and then this function is called at line 17 in "login.php".Hope this helps in understanding.

Comment: have you uploaded your site to github? 
i can assist there

Comment: Nevermind brother ,I got the solution. It was a small problem ; I needed to rename _construct in user.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `user.php`
Rename _construct to __construct. Now the constructor isn't executed, so the pdo variable will remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

add below lines to catch your exact error in your *connection.php*

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

this will show your details error exception if any available.

Comment: [I did this](https://ibb.co/PrVh5tB) and after that [I got this](https://ibb.co/5RryB0R) Thanks for the help but still the same error :(

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the variable $getFromU is an instance of the User class. But you have not yet instantiated it before using it.